# Java creating a pop up that prompts for a file path

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to create a pop up that prompts for a file path and then writes out the items that are in the default tab to a new file and tab.

I am somewhat new to Java, it needs to come back to me:

```
    Private void exportFiles(ActionEvent event) {
       JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
       fc.showSaveDialog(this);
       File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
```

I am trying to get it to come back to me, so how would I do that?

Comment: what is wrong with the code you have supplied

Comment: you want a prompt in Swing? try this `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Put here your prompt");`

Comment: `private File exportFiles(ActionEvent event) {
       JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
       fc.showSaveDialog(this);
       return fc.getSelectedFile();`?

Comment: When you wake up in the morning give your question a new read but do it pretending that you didn't write it, wipe it from your mind. Now, what does `"and then writes out the items that are in the default tab to a new file and tab"` mean? What **default tab** and what new **file** and **tab**? In what? `"I am trying to get it to come back to me"`, what is that suppose to mean? Come back to you for what? To do what with? Are we talking about the selection of a single file or multiple files? Are you looking for: `if (file != null) { System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()); }`?

Comment: so i have my gui set up where i can import items in to the main tab. I have an export button ( which is where this code is coming from) and you can choose a file and take those contents in to a new tab. Does that make sense? this is just me messing around outside of work and working on java. I am a bit stuck though. I know the code that is there already works.